# How to tell Laravel 5 to aoutoload my custom package?

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

I have create in vendor directory the following structure for my package:

```
/vendor/
    koala/
        bamboo-sdk/
             src/
                 Engine2/
                 Utils/
```

I then run

```
$composer init
```

inside koala folder.

Lately I went to Laravel5 composer.json main. And modified the autoload.psr-4 part like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        ...
        "Koala\\BambooSdk\\": "vendor/koala/bamboo-sdk/src"
    }
},
```

I then run

```
$composer dump-autoload
```

in order to have /vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php updated with the new references.

But I dont see it changing.
Also having a new controller with directive:
use Koala\BambooSdk\MyClass;

and then below 
$myobj = new MyClass();

will result in a error: 
FatalErrorException in MyController.php line 165:
Class 'Koala\BambooSdk\MyClass' not found

Comment: maybe your class isn't in root of src ?

Comment: No it's not. It's inside subfolder Engine2. How should i reference to it? By use Koala\BambooSdk\Engine2\MyClass; ?  But still can't explain ti me why autoload_classmap.php after modifying main composer.json and running dump-autoload remains unchanged...

Comment: for update autoload classmap try `dump-autoload --optimize`

Comment: for call some class from package yes you need include all folders I think `Koala\BambooSdk\Engine2\MyClass; ` will work

Comment: Ok with optimize flag I find all my classes listed in autoload_classmap.php after running a dump-autoload. But still I don't understand, once they're in autolod_classmap, why should I put a directive : use Koala\BambooSdk\Engine2\MyClass;  in my controllers? Shouldn't Laravel5 be able to reasolve autmatically the names  (having them mapped on autoload_classmap)?

Comment: How look like records about your package in autoload_classmap.php?

Comment: 'Koala\\BambooSdk\\Engine2\\MyClass' => $vendorDir . '/koala/bamboosdk/src/Engine2/MyClass.php'

Comment: This mean that you can use your class next way `use Koala\BambooSdk\Engine2\MyClass;`  more info about psr-4, autoloading, Laravel  you can find on Laracasts (for your problem https://laracasts.com/lessons/psr-4-autoloading)